# First fragment is visible even after the trasacting the second fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Initially I have two buttons in my MainActivity. Button1 corresponds to displaying the first fragment and button2 corresponds to display the second fragment.

The issue is that When the user clicks the button2, the second fragment is loaded but still the first fragment is visible. How can I be able to sort this out?

Here is the code for button1 and button2.

```
if(number == 1) {
    //button 1 pressed
    BlankFragment fragment1 = new BlankFragment();
    Fragment fragment = new FragmentTwo();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.placeFragment, fragment1);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
} 

//button2 is pressed
if(number==2) {
    FragmentTwo fragment2 = new FragmentTwo();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.placeFragment, fragment2);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Fragment one xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".BlankFragment">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagess"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="123dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="128dp"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment two xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".FragmentTwo">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4"
            >
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/itemText"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.5"
                    android:hint="@string/enter_a_item"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.5"
                    android:id="@+id/enterButton"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Enter"
                    android:onClick="onEnter"
                    android:background="@drawable/round"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            />
</LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

My Activity fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/placeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.akhilbatchu.makearecipe.BlankFragment"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me.

Comment: You can provide **white background** to main view *(`FrameLayout` in your case)* of your fragments layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are using `add` instead of `replace` somewhere in code

or

You should replace `fragment`, in your Activity fragment xml, with some empty container (e.g. FrameLayout):

replace that:

```
<fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/placeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.akhilbatchu.makearecipe.BlankFragment"/>
```

with that:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/placeFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to coloring the second fragment background like this. Also add clickable property

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:context=".FragmentTwo">
```